# How do I stop garbage collection? Maui .net c#

Tags: c#, json, .net, garbage-collection, maui

Garbage collection takes forever! after running this code Garbage collection doesnt seem to end. I'm creating app in .net maui and have 17 json files for this class to better store data. Problem is accuring whenever i start the app. Debugger console fills up with:

> [ame.codilitiapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 277(158KB)
> AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 3125KB/4167KB, paused
> 11us,6us total 4.024ms

It spams itself like forever and i dont know what to do.

Ive tried:

- Increasing ram size of android emulator, size of disc space, heap size, java heap size inside of project.

  Class code:

```cs
namespace Resources.Classes
{
    public  class Lessons
    {                                                                                                                                                                                          
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? pdf { get; set; }
        public string[]? Tasks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Repository code :

```cs
internal class Repo
{
    public Lessons[] LessonsList = new Lessons[17];

    public void RepositoryVoid()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
        {
            LoadMauiAssetLessons($"{i}.json", i--);
        }
    }

    private async void LoadMauiAssetLessons(string Path, int i)
    {
        try
        {
            using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(Path);
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Lessons>(contents) != null)
            {
                LessonsList[i] = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Lessons>(contents);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("File not found :" + ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of json file to load into lesson object:

```json
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "Iterations",
    "pdf": "https://codility.com/media/train/Iterations.pdf",
    "Tasks": [
        "BinaryGap"
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you know that GC is happening and how did you track it down to be inside GC? Which tools do you use? To me, the code looks like it shouldn't trigger GC at all for those 2 kB of memory that are used. (Except you have other JSON files that are much larger)

Comment: Debug console shows me : [monodroid-gc] 46080 outstanding GREFs. Performing a full GC!
[ame.codilitiapp] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 46755(2133KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 3106KB/4142KB, paused 10us,4us total 4.459ms    other json files looks the same. after calling repositoryvoid from other file garrbage collection starts....

Comment: I call it by :      '             Repo repository = new();
            
            repository.RepositoryVoid(); ' after deliting those 2 lines garbage collection stops

Comment: Is this `Explicit concurrent copying` coming from the suppressed exceptions block? Btw. as your `LoadMauiAssetLessons` is `async void` the deserialization tasks are basically fire and forget for the caller loop so they are running concurrently instead of after each other. Is this intentional? If not, change the signature to `async Task` and await the `LoadMauiAssetLessons` calls in the `for` loop.

Comment: IMHO, your problem is not garbage collection. You're not applying the [Task Asynchronous Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) (async/await) correctly. Does your code even finish execution? This line `LoadMauiAssetLessons($"{i}.json", i--);` is very suspicious, I would expect an infinite loop here.

Comment: await LoadMauiAssetLessons($"{i}.json", i--); shows problems :Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0012 The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'. codilitiApp (net7.0-android), codilitiApp (net7.0-ios), codilitiApp (net7.0-maccatalyst), codilitiApp (net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\GitHub\Codility_app\codilitiApp\Resources\Classes\Repository.cs 16 Active

Comment: You cannot await `async void`.

Comment: AFTER CHANGING FOR LOOP for             LoadMauiAssetLessons($"{1}.json", 0);IT STOPTED ??????

Comment: ive changed for loop for each call to void loadmauiassetlessons what is happening

Comment: When you go over your array, you do from 0, < Count, ++. And you do not modify the variable inside. Or this happens. Random use of async aside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here, but garbage collection isn't one of them.

The first problem is not applying the [async-await pattern (or Task Asynchronous Pattern)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) correctly. Instead of using `async void` and calling the asynchronous code in a *fire-and-forget* fashion, you should be using `async Task` and apply the *async-await* pattern all the way.

The second problem is your for-loop:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
{
    LoadMauiAssetLessons($"{i}.json", i--);
}
```

This probably isn't doing what you're expecting it to do. You're effectively counting `i` *up* **and** *down* in the same iteration, which causes an infinite loop and always yields the same index being passed to `LoadMauiAssetLessons()`. You should be using `i-1` instead of `i--` here:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
{
    LoadMauiAssetLessons($"{i}.json", i-1);
}
```

Finally, your code should look something like this:

```cs
internal class Repo
{
    public Lessons[] LessonsList = new Lessons[17];

    public async Task RepositoryVoid()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
        {
            await LoadMauiAssetLessons($"{i}.json", i-1);
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadMauiAssetLessons(string Path, int i)
    {
        try
        {
            using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(Path);
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Lessons>(contents) != null)
            {
                LessonsList[i] = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Lessons>(contents);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("File not found :" + ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the loop should run from 0 to 17 instead.

Comment: I agree, but I wanted to keep as much of the original code as possible for the OP to see the problem.